# connect multiple server in single codeigniter application

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, master-slave

I am trying to connect multiple server connection in 
application/config/database.php file
actually I am trying to master slave database in CodeIgniter

### here is my database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['password'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['database'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

/*
$active_group = 'anotherdb';
$active_record = TRUE;*/

$db['anotherdb']['hostname'] = 'xx.xx.xxx.xx';
$db['anotherdb']['username'] = 'xxuser';
$db['anotherdb']['password'] = 'xxxx';
$db['anotherdb']['database'] = 'xxx';
$db['anotherdb']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['anotherdb']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['anotherdb']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['anotherdb']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['anotherdb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['anotherdb']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['anotherdb']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['anotherdb']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['anotherdb']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['anotherdb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['anotherdb']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

### and here is my controller code

```
$a = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
$b = $this->load->database('anotherdb', TRUE);
echo "<br>".$a->conn_id;
echo "<br>".$b->conn_id;
```

## but error comes as :

A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 338

Comment: Which connection did make the error, 'defalt' or 'anotherdb'?

Comment: And please provide some log about your connection error, becouse it may be just wrong username-password or 3306 is not accessable at your "anotherdb" setup from your current IP.

Answer (score 1):

Go in php.ini file. Check that the property mysql.default_socket have valid directory.
I think you can't make and single mysql connection.
What is your OS?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

Following codes are helpfull for me
https://gist.github.com/fideloper/3137896